# Drupal Preview/Edit Broken? Any Autosave for CCK?

Tags: php, drupal

### I have a simple Content Type for a page of a textbox for "Name". Allowing all users to edit, I notice that if I have a single page with that content type displaying a single CCK field and I want to change from Jacob to John:

### Name: Jacob

There are two options "Edit" and "View"

When I click "Edit", it allows me to edit John to say "Johnn".

Then I click "Preview" to Preview my changes.

I notice that "Johnn" was spelled incorrectly, so I click "Edit" at the top of the page.

I notice that the "Johnn" change is lost, and what is shown in the textbox is "Jacob"

Is there some module or something that preserves changes/autosaves when switching back from preview to edit mode?

Comment: please use larger and bolder fonts, they can't read this from space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Preview, you should be able to edit the content directly below the Preview output.  There should be no need to click the Edit tab again to edit since that will refresh the page which means that you do lose your unsaved changes.